# Error compiling modular code in VSC using gcc

Tags: c, gcc, modular-design

I've a problem compiling the following programm:

```
// hauptteil.c (main part)
#include "nebenfkt.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int x =10;
    int ergebnis=0;
    ergebnis =ver(x);
    printf("Doubled number: %d", ergebnis);
    return 0;
}
```

```
//nebenfkt.h
int ver(int x);
```

```
#include "nebenfkt.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int ver(int x)
{
    int rueck;
    rueck= x*2;
    return rueck;
}
```

VSC gives me the feedback "* undefined reference to `ver'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status*"

### Solution

The problem occurred because I only used the command "gcc hauptteil.c -o function"
Instead of "gcc hauptteil.c nebenfkt.c -o function"

Comment: There is nothing called `ausgabe` in this code.

Comment: Forgive me, it was from my second try ausgabe is the same as ver. I fixed the text

Comment: What command is used to compile the code? It needs to be passed both `.c` files.

Comment: @vukstudent: could you move the solution to the answer section? Self-answered questions are welcome here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was discovered by Eugene Sh.

My mistake was that I only used the command "gcc hauptteil.c -o function" Instead of "gcc hauptteil.c nebenfkt.c -o function".